# v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, web, webpack

My react app which is made using custom webpack config. And using **Node JS 8.4**.
Now I want to upgrade the version from **8.4** to node **12 LTS**.

I can successfully run the project using **node 9.11**. but unable to run in **node 12** and **node 10**.

I attach the error screenshot of error. Also packages installing successfully.

I am using **"webpack": "^3.5.3"**. Also tried with updating node-sass.

[image]

Comment: If you're going to upgrade, you might as well go to Node version 18 or 20. Since these are [currently being maintained](https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases).

Comment: @Reyno I am trying to upgrade it one by one version.
I also tried with 18 and 20 version. 
getting same error.

Comment: An assertion failure in a builtin, followed by a core dump, hints at a serious bug in nodejs or the way webpack is using it. Try to reproduce it with the latest versions of all involved components, build a [mcve] for others to try, and report it as an issue.